# I have tried to write a function to deliver an SQL query but I keep receiving an error

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am trying to write a function to create a table from user inputs (written in python3.10). Here is the code I have:

```
`def getDatabaseCursor(host, username, password, database):
    global mydb
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=username,
        password=password,
        database=database
    )
    global mycursor
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    Classes.sqlCursor(mycursor, mydb)
    print("\nTables in database:")
    mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
    for x in mycursor:
        print('-'+x[0])
    print()
    print("Please choose a table to view/modify")
    table = input()
    mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
    for x in mycursor:
        if (x[0]) == table:
            print()
            options(table)
        else:
            print("Create table?")
            create = input("y/n ")
            if create == "y":
                createTable(table)
                return None
            return None
    return None


def createTable(tableName):
    print("Create table called:", tableName)
    print("How many columns?")
    columns = input()
    columns = int(columns)
    count = 1
    columnNames = []
    while columns != 0:
        print("Column", count, "name:")
        columnX_Names = input()
        columnNames.append(columnX_Names)
        columns = columns - 1
        count = count + 1
    print("Confirm column names")
    for x in columnNames:
        print(x)
    answer = input("y/n ")
    if answer == "y":
        print(columnNames[0])
        print(tableName)
        mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" (temp VARCHAR(255))")
        count = 0
        for x in columnNames:
            sql = "ALTER TABLE "+tableName+" ADD COLUMN ("+x+" VARCHAR(255))"
            mycursor.execute(sql)
            print(sql)
        print(sql)
        mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE "+tableName+" DROP COLUMN TEMP")`
```

However, everytime I run the code it delivers an error message when it tries to create a table. Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/ObjectOrientedProgramming/Admin.py", line 226, in <module>
    getDatabaseCursor("localhost", username, password, database)
  File "/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/ObjectOrientedProgramming/Admin.py", line 78, in getDatabaseCursor
    createTable(table, mydb)
  File "/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/ObjectOrientedProgramming/Admin.py", line 161, in createTable
    mydb.cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" (temp VARCHAR(255))")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1430, in cursor
    self.handle_unread_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1741, in handle_unread_result
    raise InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

I have tried rewriting the string for the SQL query and triple checked that it is the correct syntax. I have tried printing the SQL query and it displays exactly correct. Anybody know what is causing this or what I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-using the same cursor to execute a new `CREATE TABLE` query, when that cursor still has unread results remaining from the previous `SHOW TABLES` query.

You have to fetch **all** the results from the cursor, before using that same cursor to execute a new query.  Or else use a new cursor for the new query.

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you so much, that works! You have no idea how long I've been stuck on that XD